# What other languages, beside Transact SQL, state that 22/7 is equal to 3?

Tags: math, languages

I was using Microsoft SQL Query Analyzer the other day and wrote a very simple select statement:

```
SELECT 22/7 as [PI Equiv]
```

I was suprized that the result was 3, when I was expecting to see 3.1428571. Even if you declare the output to be `Numeric(18,7)`, you still get 3.0000000.

```
DECLARE @Answer Numeric(18,7)
SET @Answer = 22/7
SELECT @Answer as [PI Equiv]

RESULT = 3.0000000
```

What other languages return integer values when the dividend and divisor are both integers?

Comment: Weird... what happens if you try `SELECT 22.0/7.0 as [PI Equiv]` ?

Comment: When you divide 22/7.0 Transact SQL returns 3.142857. This could be a pitfall if you didn't know about it.

Comment: almost all languages return int when both are int, except those who have different operators for division (ex. pascal: 22/7=3.1428571 and 22 div 7=3)

Comment: What do you mean "declare the output to be Numeric(18,7)"? Do you mean casting the result?

Comment: @JohnFx - If Answer was a field in a database table you have to define it as a specific type for example numeric(18,7). Declare in effect does the same thing.

Comment: @Cape Code Gunny - Code example. I still don't see what you are talking about. Where the result goes has nothing to do with how an expression is evaluated.

Comment: @JohnFx - Sorry I left off the result. Please see above.

Comment: Okay. My point still stands. What you do with the result of the equation (in this case putting it in a type that allows decimals) has no bearing on the way the formula is calculated. 22/7 is being calculated as 3 and then 3 is being cast into the appropriate data type implicitly. You aren't "declaring the output" in your example. You have to change your inputs to 22.0/7.0 to achieve what you are trying to do.

Comment: 3 is the correct answer. In integer arithmetic, 22/7 is 3 remainder 1. The quotient is 3. It has nothing to do with the dividend and divisor being integers, it has to do with the use of integer division. (How you specify integer division depends on the language, but I know of no language that bases it on whether the inputs are integers or not. For example, try 22.0/7.0 -- still two integers, but you will not get integer division.)

Comment: @David Schwartz - 22.0 is not an integer in tsql.

Comment: 22.0 is an integer. An "integer" is a whole number, a number that is not a fraction. It may not be an "int" or a "smallint" as TSQL defines those types, but it's definitely an integer.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Most languages that supports integer arithmetic will give you 3 from the calculation `22/7`. This includes, C, C++, C#, Ada, Java, etc. The exceptions appear to be Pascal, VB and Lisp that do floating point arithmetic by default.

Languages where you have implicit typing *may* give you a floating point result instead, though I would check it first.

However, it's bad programming practice and if you mean floating point division you should make at least one of the values explicitly floating point:

```
pi = 22.0 / 7;
```

Comment: Almost, but not quite, true. Pascal (for one example) *does* support integer arithmetic, but `/` always does floating point division; to get integer division you use `div`. Many versions of Lisp do roughly the same as well.

Comment: @Jerry - thanks for the extra info. It's been 30 years since I did Pascal ;)

Comment: VB would also give you a fraction, to get integer division it would be `22 \ 7`.

Comment: If anyone else has any exceptions please feel free to edit them in

Comment: @Chris - I started with Pascal and it has always been there. I knew about the div for integer division. It's only recently reared it's head because I ran into a situation where I was building complicated calculations based on interim calculation results and the answers were skewed.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't specifically ask, but I thought I'd add that if you don't want an integer result you do this:

```
SELECT 22/7.0 as [PI Equiv]
```

or

```
SELECT 22/cast(7 as numeric (18.2)) as [PI Equiv]
```

Casting an output variable did nothing because the calculation is done before the variable value is set.  Division in SQL should explicitly specify that one of the elements is a decimal if you want a decimal result. You also should almost never do a division without  a case statement to make sure that the divide by 0 possibility will be handled unless the divisor is a hardcoded value such as the 7 in your calculation.

```
declare @somenumber numeric(18,2)
set @somenumber = 0
SELECT CASE where  @somenumber = 0 then null else 22/@somenumber end as [PI Equiv]
```

Answer (score 2):

**In integer arithmetic, the remainder is ignored**. This is standard behaviour in most modern languages, initially included in programming languages due to hardware limitations and performance constraints.

For historic and performance reasons, this behaviour is present in most modern languages/platforms; you'll have to go out of your way to find a language which doesn't behave in this manner (examples of exceptions include some experiments with  Smalltalk and related).

Comment: Well, and also done because it makes sense. Most of the time, you want the quotient and not the remainder, and having a basic division operation the returned two values would make the syntax overly complex.

Answer (score 1):

Python 2.x (without the `-Q new` option or `from __future__ import division`)

```
>>> 22/7
3
```

bash

```
$ expr 22 / 7
3
```

Java

```
class Div{
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        int x = 22/7;
        System.out.println( "22/7=" + x );
    }
}

$ java Div
22/7=3
```

Comment: `s/Python/Python 2.x/` - in Python 3, `/` is always "full" division though - `//` is used for truncating division.

Comment: @delnan: since the question is so bad; we can easily assume that `22//7` is the Python equivalent to the TSQL expression is in the question

Comment: @S.Lott - What makes it a bad question?

Comment: @Cape Cod Gunny: the use of integer math (`22/7`) leading to an integer result shouldn't lead to an open-ended question like this.  It seems like such a simple fact about programming languages.